# Bootstrap alert in css not applied

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, playframework

I have tried to display bootstrap(Version 3.3.5) alert  in my login form when login fails or inputs not filed. here is my login.scala.html

```
@(content: Html)(implicit messages: Messages,flash: play.api.mvc.Flash)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>   @Messages("application.name")</title>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("jquery/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css")">

        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/login.css")">
    </head>
    <body>

        <header class="topbar">
            <h1 class="fill">
               @Messages("application.name")
            </h1>
        </header>

        <section id="main">
            <center>

                  @if(flash.get("success").isDefined){
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                     <strong>Success!</strong> @flash.get("success")
                </div>
                }

                @if(flash.get("error").isDefined){
                <div class="alert alert-error">
                     <strong>Error!</strong> @flash.get("error")
                </div>
                }


                 @content
            </center>

        </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

Given paths are correct but I`m confused why these css are not applied for alerts only, look this snap shot
[image]

if anyone can give a solution its appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's no `alert-error` in Bootstrap, most probably you want to use `alert-danger`.